# Where to find CabWiz.exe

Tags: windows-mobile, sdk, setup-deployment, cabwiz

I am resetting up my development machine and I cannot seem to remember where I got CabWiz.exe (used for creating installation cab files for windows mobile).

Is that on MSDN Downloads in some package?  Or somewhere else?  Does anyone know?

I installed the Windows Mobile 5 SDK and I thought that was all I needed, but I guess there is something else I need.

I asked the MS Concierge and they said that it comes with platform builder (which I would install anyway), but the path is not the same as what I had.

It was at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\SmartDevices\SDK\SDKTools\cabwiz.exe
and he told me it is at \CEPB\Bin\cabwiz.exe.  I am concerned that I am missing something else....

---

**Later note**: Right, so, I am not so smart.  My MSBuild script was failing to find

- *C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\SmartDevices\SDK\SDKTools\cabwiz.exe*.

And that is with good reason, because I installed on a 64 bit os.  So it is now at

- *C:\Program Files **(x86)**\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\SmartDevices\SDK\SDKTools\cabwiz.exe*

Some times I am just super short sighted!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`%PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\SmartDevices\SDK\SDKTools`

or

`%PROGRAMFILES%\Windows Mobile 6 SDK\Tools\CabWiz`

Comment: But it is not there.  I don't have SmartDevices\SDK\SDKTools What do I need to install to get that?

Comment: I am dumb.  I have a 64 bit os now so it is in *Program Files (x86)*